# How to deal with missing value in Pandas DataFrame from open data?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have downloaded ten open datasets of air pollution in 2010-2019 (which has been transferred to Pandas DataFrame by 'read_csv') that have some missing values.

The rows are ordered by each day including several items (like PM2.5, SO2,...). Most of the data include 17 or 18 items. There are 27 columns which separately are Year, Station, Item, 00, 01, ..., 23.

In this case, I already used
`df.fillna(np.nan).apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce')`
and `df.interpolate(axis=1,inplace=True)`

But now if the data have missing values from '00' to anytime following, the interpolate function would not works. If I want to fill all these blanks, I need to merge the last day data which is not null and use `interpolate` again.

However, different days have different items numbers, which means there are still some rows that can't be filled.

In a nutshell, now I'm trying to contact all data by the key of items and use `interpolate`.

By the way, after data cleaning, I would like to apply to `xgboost` and linear regression to predict PM2.5. Is there any way recommended to deal with the data?
(Or any demo code online?)

For example, the data would be like:
[one of the datasets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS5mH.png)

I used `df.groupby('date').size()` and got
[size of different days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKYh5.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. I recommend you to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Or in other words, how to split different days and concat together?
`Groupby(['date','items'])`? and then how to merge?

Or, is that possible to interpolate from the last value of the last row?

Comment: Please use the **Your Answer** button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.